# Update of a row in asp.net MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I've got an Edit action like this:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(UserModel user1)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        UserManager um = new UserManager();
        String mail = User.Identity.Name;
        long id = um.getUserIDByemail(mail);
        user user = db.users.Single(u => u.user_id == id);
        user.name = user1.name;
        user.cellno = user1.cellno;
        db.users.Attach(user);
        db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(user, EntityState.Modified);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(user1);
}
```

I've got user object exactly what I want to update. Two properties (`name`, `cellno`) of user comes from a view. When I run it I get an error:

> The object cannot be attached because it is already in the object context. An object can only be reattached when it is in an unchanged state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can just remove the Attach and it should work.

Comment: Yes.... it works!!! Thanks a lot @ tzerb.Can you Please explain me what was the problem...?

Comment: Your user object was already in the users collection.  You're just updating it.  What version of EF are you using?